# Include html content inside svg for Report

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highcharts

I have an Highchart(SVG ) with Some Title and a table in a modal. I want take a report of the whole modal. But only Highchart is coming in the report.

```
highchartsExport.nativeSVGtoImage($("#popup_trending").find("svg")[0],function(uri){
var data = $.param({'dataURL': uri, 'emailContent': $scope.content});
var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf;'}}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "take a report"?

Comment: I want to convert the svg(highchart) and html content title and table to an image in a base 64 format and sent to backend. while using htm2canvas the image is not clear so i go with highchart export but i need the table and title also @BarbaraLaird

Comment: You can render title and table in svg which will be exported with the chart http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table